# Horizontal Smooth Scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to create a smooth scrolling horizontal effect based on anchoring. i.e. the fixed navigation links scroll to an anchor (e.g. id="#two") on the click.

I have been able to do a vertical scroll using the CSS Tricks example. (http://css-tricks.com/examples/SmoothPageScroll/#) but cannot for the life of me apply the same smooth scroll to a horizontal situation.

Background: I am trying to create a film-strip effect.

Comment: have you tried http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/ ?

Comment: I can't add an answer with just a link so I'm adding a comment with the link: http://praneetloke.github.com/left-right

Answer (score 0):

You scroll by doing:

$(....).animate({scrollLeft: ####});

You can adjust the animation by setting a speed (duration) and an easing (the "style" of the action).

You get the number to go in scrollLeft by checking the `offset()` of the element you want to scroll to.

Answer (score 0):

**2022 Update for future readers** 
I've recently published a cross-browser **smooth-scrolling API that solves this** and many other smooth-scrolling related problems.

With the API you can scroll to a certain X or Y, by a certain amount or scrollIntoView any element you want.

The API works with any element (window, document, body, your custom div, ecc...) and **every scroll can be cancelled at any time!**

In this case the problem would be solved by simply calling the API function `uss.hrefSetup` which sets up smooth-scrolling anchors for you.

If you just want to horizontally smooth-scroll an element you can use the `uss.scrollXTo(finalXPosition, yourContainer)` or `uss.scrollXBy(deltaX, yourContainer)`.
Where:

- `youContainer` is the DOM element you want to scroll (the document is the default one)
- `finalXPosition` is the "scroll-width" you want the left border of your container to be at the end of the scroll-animation
- `deltaX` is the number of pixels you want you cointainer to be scrolled by.

Here you can find all the documentation: [GITHUB REPO](https://github.com/CristianDavideConte/universalSmoothScroll)